# selinux what are the differences between setenforce 0 to permanent selinux

Tags: centos, selinux

regarding to selinux and according to some Hadoop recommendation selinux must be disabled

about selinux - more info in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STXKQY_BDA_SHR/bl1bda_selinux.htm

we have two options

1. login to machine and set selinux `setenforce 0`. Or
2. login to machine and edit `/etc/selinux/config` by set SELINUX to `disabled`

so is there any difference bitten disable SELinux on CentOS 7 temporarily, as `setenforce 0`, to edit `/etc/selinux/config` file and set the SELINUX to disabled ?

from documentation we can see "*If you are using Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP) in any IBM Spectrum scale release, SELinux must be disabled*."

so maybe we should not take a risks and set the selinux to disable and restart the machine , ?

note I assume that set the selinux to disable require machine restart ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setenforce 0` will only temporarily disable SELinux. The next time you reboot the server, selinux will be back on.

When you edit `/etc/selinux/config`, that makes the change persistent across reboots.

Generally speaking, if at all possible, you should keep SELinux turned on. `setenforce 0` allows you to troubleshoot issues with the goal of turning it back on (with `setenforce 1`).

But there are indeed some vendors out there who unfortunately insist on disabling it completely. I personally try to avoid such vendors.

Comment: in our servers the default mode - is selinux in permissive mode , so you suggest to disabled it in the file and do a reboot?

Comment: You can set selinux to Permissive mode in /etc/selinux/config as well. To clarify my above statement, permissive mode is generally used for troubleshooting problems. Permissive mode will allow everything to work, but will still log failures. Enforcing mode will log and block failures. When selinux is turned off completely, you don't even get log files.

Comment: so back to the doc - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STXKQY_BDA_SHR/bl1bda_selinux.htm , since Cloudera HDP say to set it to disable and perform the reboot , do you agree with there suggestion ?

Comment: If the vendor says you should disable it, and you trust the vendor, then it's really a business decision. Do you go with that vendor's product, or not? If you go with the vendor, and you trust them, then follow their documentation, unless you're prepared to use the product without official support.

Comment: The proper way to solve this is to create a SELinux policy for that software. Meantime ask the vendor to write a proper SELinux policy and include it in their package(s).